# Rendering plotted waveform data from JS file

Tags: javascript, json, html5-canvas

So I have waveforms of audio files that have already been plotted in JS files. They are stored remotely, (eg: http://www.example.com/file.js) and they spit out following as seen in [THIS](http://pastebin.com/AebiMAyv) pastebin.

I have searched high and low but can't find how I would render this in a div on the browser. I'm guessing that it uses canvas?

If somebody could show me a simple fiddle with how this works, or point me to a resource that explains it I'd greatly appreciate it.

!EDIT! I've attached an image to show you how it could be rendered (just the white bars, minus the background image of course).

[image]

Comment: given data is array of integers so how to consider `x,y` points for plotting?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Can you show some sample graph what you are expecting from this data?

Comment: Sure, any of the waveforms on here - https://hearthis.at/ - the plotted JS data I attached is waveform data for a track from the hearthis API.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. How do the numbers in your array relate to the results you want displayed? Maybe post an image (your hearthis.at link is just a homepage).

Comment: I've attached an image to show you exactly how this plotted js file is being rendered.

Comment: @Grant. That's done simply. Just iterate through the array and draw a line path for each value in the array `.beginPath(); .moveTo(x,bottomY); .lineTo(x,bottomY-ArrayValue); .stroke(); x+=3;`

Comment: @markE I kinda guessed the logic behind it but I have no idea how to do what you've suggested. Is it done with canvas or something else? Could you possibly show me an example or point me to a resource that explains how it's done please?

Comment: I understand the concept of iterating through the array but how do I spit out the elements?

Comment: @Grant. Html5 canvas doesn't create elements, it just draws shapes. For your waveform you draw a set of vertical lines. [Here's a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) to get you started. Since your project is simple, you probably only need to review the first 2 sections of the tutorial at the bottom. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE thanks mate, will get stuck in ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to loop through the array. Prerequisites would be :

- Scale the canvas so that all lines fit inside - use number of entries in this case to determine final width and maximum value of the array (or a static factor if you know the total range).
- Optionally transform the canvas so that the coordinate system uses 0 as bottom of canvas.
- If there is too much data you can skip some of the points (shown below)

Here is an example:

```
var step = 4,                               // 2 points for line, 2 for space
    skip = 1,                               // only use every n. point
    width = data.length * step / skip,      // width of waveform
    maxY = 0,                               // see below
    i;

// find max height
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i += skip)
    if (data[i] > maxY) maxY = data[i];     // store the highest value

// transform the canvas using scale factors. The -height is to flip the coordinate system
ctx.transform(c.width / width, 0, 0, -c.height / maxY, 0, c.height);

// now add each bar to the path
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i += skip)
    ctx.rect(i * step, 0, 2, data[i]);

// rasterize all bars at one (black here, use fillStyle to set different color)
ctx.fill()
```

Working example provided below -

```js
function plot(data) {
 var c = document.querySelector("canvas"),
  ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
  step = 3,           // 2 points for line, 1 for space
  width = data.length * step,
  maxY = 0,
  i;

    // find max height
 for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  if (data[i] > maxY) maxY = data[i];

 ctx.transform(c.width / width, 0, 0, -c.height / maxY, 0, c.height);  // scale horizontally and flip coordinate system
 
 for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  ctx.rect(i * step, 0, 2, data[i]);
  
 ctx.fill()
}

plot([148,154,144,153,171,165,170,170,162,174,169,172,169,179,196,177,204,171,174,175,169,177,178,182,173,194,179,185,177,173,174,174,165,171,183,173,188,177,173,170,172,177,167,196,177,173,187,176,181,176,176,171,172,155,146,150,151,144,149,151,157,148,150,141,143,139,138,170,176,168,176,184,174,172,173,164,166,162,173,169,157,179,157,170,171,170,181,162,177,162,178,166,173,168,166,174,170,169,171,176,185,172,182,173,172,164,177,161,171,167,170,166,159,165,163,170,179,149,149,143,147,145,142,137,157,141,142,151,139,162,167,169,169,171,170,161,159,164,157,160,159,171,175,181,170,170,175,171,189,164,181,172,175,191,168,176,165,163,157,172,171,168,160,164,165,168,172,173,168,176,172,178,169,172,179,171,171,171,176,167,174,168,175,174,171,182,178,181,166,175,162,179,184,175,183,183,194,196,192,198,192,195,193,198,204,195,222,201,198,199,190,201,188,199,193,161,198,188,183,184,197,188,187,183,185,182,200,193,193,186,202,189,195,186,188,191,194,203,193,189,184,192,179,175,163,174,170,178,181,167,179,174,182,182,174,171,158,180,187,176,172,176,182,176,153,155,187,182,189,189,180,205,189,186,191,182,194,184,202]); // cut short for demo
```

```html
<canvas width=640 height=50></canvas>
```